# Cannot create a path using boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to create a one path from another:

```
path;//this is somewhere else correctly created path from a string
```

but when I try this:

```
boost::filesystem3::path project_path(path.begin(),path.end());
```

I'm getting an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'convert(const   
boost::filesystem3::path*, const boost::filesystem3::path*,   
boost::filesystem3::path::string_type&, const codecvt_type&)'
```

Anyone knows what's going on?

EDIT

```
auto beg_ = path.begin();
        auto end_ = path.end() - 1;//this line causes no advance defined error.  
//    If I try to do:  
    boost::filesystem3::path some_path(path.begin(),path.end() - 1); I'm getting the before mentioned (original error).
```

I have nowhere defined any macro on my own.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like `path` is of the type `boost::filesystem3::path` and not a `std::string`.  The constructor in Boost getting called is likely

```
template <class InputIterator>
path(InputIterator begin, InputIterator end)
{ 
  if (begin != end)
  {
    std::basic_string<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIterator>::value_type>
      s(begin, end);
    path_traits::convert(s.c_str(), s.c_str()+s.size(), m_pathname, codecvt());
  }
}
```

If I'm not mistaken, `InputIterator` is being interpreted as `boost::filesystem3::path*`.  If that's the case, then yes, the call to `path_traits::convert(s.c_str(), s.c_str()+s.size(), m_pathname, codecvt())` will likely not match any existing method signatures for `path_traits::convert()`

See if using a `std::string` for the `path` variable works instead -- like so

```
std::string somePath = "/some/path";

boost::filesystem3::path project_path(somePath.begin(), somePath.end());
```

Although if you're going to do that, it'd be easier to just do

```
boost::filesystem3::path(somePath);
```

Comment: I've tried to do auto beg = path.begin(), and I'm getting an error: 'class boost::filesystem3::path::iterator' has no member named 'advance' any reason why?

Comment: Actually, that's odd -- just took the time to trace my way through the inheritance of `path::iterator`, and unless you have `BOOST_NO_STD_ITERATOR` defined and you don't have `BOOST_MSVC_STD_ITERATOR` defined via your preprocessor defines, `path::iterator` should ultimately inherit from `std::iterator`, which does have a member named `advance`, described at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/advance/.

Comment: Could you post a larger snippet of the code you're working with -- in particular, I'd like to see the code where you're defining your iterator variables, your string variable, etc.

Comment: #hatboyzero updated, see OP, and if you need any more info just let me know. By the way, thanks for taking interest.

Comment: Have you tried getting a `std::string` from the `path` variable via `path.string()` and then passing the `begin()` and `end()` iterators of said `std::string` to the `boost::filesystem3::path` constructor?

Comment: Just following up here -- did this answer your original question regarding there being no matching function call for `convert()`?  As for the `no advance` error you're experiencing, I *think* that may be due to trying to increment/decrement from the iterator returned by `path.end()`.  I think this is invalid due to the fact that `path.end()` returns the equivalent of an uninitialized iterator -- could be wrong, though... :)

Comment: yes, convert has been mentioned. Yes, increment is not allowed, but for the fact that this is a directory iterator what is being returned not path iterator, and obviously there isn't sense subtracting/adding iterators

Comment: Duly noted -- just checking since there hasn't been a lot of activity on this question as of late...